# groupby for flavor with shape in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have data like :

```
{ordered:'111',flavor:'oreo',shape:'no1'},
{ordered:'112',flavor:'oreo',shape:'no2'},
{ordered:'113',flavor:'oreo',shape:'no2'}
```

and I want to show all flavor with count and different shape with count how to write mongoldb query for this.

I have tried this one(mongodb):

```
collection.aggregate([{
                    '$match': {
                        'preparationDate': { $eq: checkdate },
                        'status': { $ne: "CANC" },
                    }
                },
                {
                    $group:{
                        _id:{
                            flavor:"$flavor"
                        },
                        totalFlavorCount: { '$sum': 1 },
                        size: { $push:"$size" }
                    }
}])
```

o/p should be group by flavor with totalflovercount with sizes of that flavor with size count I have sizes but I can't get count of that sizes.
As shown in image I want total of no1 and no2 like no1 : 1 and no2 : 2

[image]

Comment: what is the expected o/p that you're looking at from provided sample docs ?

Comment: I think [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) or [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) in your `$group` stage should solve your problem

Comment: from your sample input there are only 2 `oreo`s with `no1` and `no2`, how to get to the output of 3 and `no2, no2, no2` ?

Comment: I.e for example data

Answer (score 0):

Query can be written something like this.

```
collection.aggregate([{
                    '$match': {
                        'preparationDate': { $eq: checkdate },
                        'status': { $ne: "CANC" },
                    }
                },
                {
                    $group:{
                        _id:{
                            flavor: "$flavor",
                            shape: "$shape"
                        },
                        totalFlavorCount: { '$sum': 1 },
                        size: { $push:"$size" }
                    }
}])
```

[Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3VNOc3PgPXH)